# Unload bootstrap in error view of main site controller

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-modules

My admin module is using bootstrap:

```
'admin'=>array(
        'preload'=>array('bootstrap'),
        'components'=>array(
            'bootstrap'=>array(
                'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
            ),
        )
    ),
```

But it also is using the error handler of the main site:

```
public function init() {
    $this->setImport(array(
        'admin.models.*',
        'admin.components.*',
    ));

    Yii::app()->setComponents(array(
       'errorHandler'=>array('errorAction'=>'site/error'),
    ));

    $this->layout = 'admin';
}
```

The problem is that when an error is generated, the bootstrap css is getting loaded screwing the layout out. How do I unload bootstrap just in the error action?

Comment: I dont know this will work do a `Yii::app()->clientScript->reset()` inside `actionError()`. This might clear all the script registerd through `clientScript`

Comment: @dInGd0nG was just about to add that as an answer, it'll work

Comment: but ther is a problem. It will clear all the script files registered. We want to reset only the files registered by `bootstrap` component

Comment: Yeah I just need bootstrap stuff unloaded...

Comment: keeg and @dInGd0nG I think it'll still work, i have tried to explain in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general to unload a component, you can use [`setComponent`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModule#setComponent-detail), passing the 2nd parameter as `null`. An example:

```
Yii::app()->getModule('admin')->setComponent('bootstrap', null);
```

However in your case, the version of bootstrap-extension you are using, **already registers the css/js as soon as the component is loaded**<sup>1</sup>. Therefore even if you unload the component, the bootstrap css will still be included and ofcourse styles will still be applied.

But we can remove the css/js registered by bootstrap, and thus remove the effect of the bootstrap component. The simplest way to do this is by resetting the `clientScript` as already discussed in comments, and the best place to [`reset`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#reset-detail) the `clientScript` is in the `actionError()` like so:

```
public function actionError() {
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error) {
        Yii::app()->clientScript->reset();
        // ... more code ...
    }
}
```

**Why** this will work is because, most of the `register*` functions to register css/js will be encountered in the *views*, and *layouts*, so any css/js registered there will be loaded, but bootstrap will be omitted. Moreover any widgets that you might be using, will register their css/js only when they are encountered by `render`.

---

<sup>1</sup>See *extensions/bootstrap/components/Bootstrap.php*'s `init()`:

```
if ($this->coreCss !== false)
    $this->registerCoreCss();

if ($this->responsiveCss !== false)
    $this->registerResponsiveCss();

if ($this->yiiCss !== false)
    $this->registerYiiCss();

if ($this->enableJS !== false)
    $this->registerCoreScripts();
```

---

With newer versions (since 1.0.1) of the extension, you have to register the css/js explicitly.